# Read MySQL Decimal with Apache Spark without losing precision

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

How to read column from MySQL type numeric(50,10) with Apache Spark without losing precision.

When reading column with Spark, it throws an error

```
An error occurred while calling o815.save. Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Spark only supports precision up to 38 ([documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType.html)).